# Not getting desired checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

**What I want :**

When I click on "Reporting" checkbox, it should check all the checkboxes below it. I mean
all check boxes below "Reporting", "Email Group","SMS Group","States Group","Call Results
Group" as shown in the image. I think this is what an ideal case will look like

**What is happening right now:**

When I click on "Reporting" , only check boxes that get checked are starting from
"Report Campaigns" to "Reporting Test New". Nothing happens to 
"Email Group" and it's children checkboxes and similarly for SMS Group,States Group
and Call Results Group. So, I have to manually click on "email group" and other group to select its childrens.

I have defined the following function I am using in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYSRp/) here:

```
function parentCheckboxCheck(obj, childrenClass, parentId ){
    if(parentId == '' ){
        if($(obj).is(':checked')){
            $(childrenClass).attr('disabled',false);
            $(childrenClass).attr('checked',true);
        }
        else {
            $(childrenClass).attr('checked',false);
            $(childrenClass).attr('disabled',true);
        }

    }else{
        if($(obj).is(':checked') && $('#'+parentId).is(':checked')){
            $(childrenClass).attr('disabled',false);
            $(childrenClass).attr('checked',true);
        }
        else {
            $(childrenClass).attr('checked',false);
            $(childrenClass).attr('disabled',true);
        }
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/VKV7t/1/

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here or what modifications are required?

Here is my coldfusion code:

```
<ul class="list_permisstion">

            <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,Reporting_Title) GT 0>
                <span class="label_permission">
                    <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                    <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,Reporting_Title) GT 0>
                        <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                    </cfif> 
                    <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_Title#" id="Reporting" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.ReportingChilds', '')" value="#Reporting_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                    <label class="label_permission" for="Reporting">#Reporting_Title#</label>
                </span>
            </cfif>

            <ul class="list_permisstion">

                <cfloop array="#Reporting_List#" index="ListLoop" >

                    <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,ListLoop) GT 0>
                        <li>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                            <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,ListLoop) GT 0>
                                <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                            </cfif>
                            <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="ReportingChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                            <label for="label_permission">#ListLoop#</label>
                        </li>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>


            </ul>
            <!--- For Email Group --->
            <ul class="list_permisstion">

                <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,Reporting_Group_Title) GT 0>
                    <span class="label_permission"> 
                        <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                        <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,Reporting_Group_Title) GT 0>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                        </cfif> 
                        <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_Group_Title#" id="ReportGroup" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.reportGroupChilds','Reporting')" class="reportingChilds" value="#Reporting_Group_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                        <label for="ReportGroup">#Reporting_Group_Title#</label> 
                    </span>
                </cfif>

                <cfloop array="#Reporting_Group_List#" index="ListLoop" >

                    <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,ListLoop) GT 0>
                        <li>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                            <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,ListLoop) GT 0>
                                <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                            </cfif>
                            <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="reportGroupChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                            <label for="ReportGroup">#ListLoop#</label>
                        </li>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            </ul>
             <!--- For SMS Group --->
             <ul class="list_permisstion">

                <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,Reporting_SMS_Group_Title) GT 0>
                    <span class="label_permission"> 
                        <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                        <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,Reporting_SMS_Group_Title) GT 0>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                        </cfif> 
                        <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_SMS_Group_Title#" id="ReportSMSGroup" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.reportSMSGroupChilds','Reporting')" class="reportingSMSChilds" value="#Reporting_SMS_Group_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                        <label for="ReportSMSGroup">#Reporting_SMS_Group_Title#</label> 
                    </span>
                </cfif>

                <cfloop array="#Reporting_SMSGroup_List#" index="ListLoop" >

                    <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,ListLoop) GT 0>
                        <li>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                            <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,ListLoop) GT 0>
                                <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                            </cfif>
                            <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="reportSMSGroupChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                            <label for="ReportSMSGroup">#ListLoop#</label>
                        </li>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            </ul> 
            <!--- For STATES GROUP --->
            <ul class="list_permisstion">

                <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,Reporting_States_Group_Title) GT 0>
                    <span class="label_permission"> 
                        <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                        <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,Reporting_States_Group_Title) GT 0>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                        </cfif> 
                        <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_States_Group_Title#" id="ReportSTATESGroup" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.reportSTATESGroupChilds','Reporting')" class="reportingSTATESChilds" value="#Reporting_States_Group_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                        <label for="ReportSTATESGroup">#Reporting_States_Group_Title#</label> 
                    </span>
                </cfif>

                <cfloop array="#Reporting_StatesGroup_List#" index="ListLoop" >

                    <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,ListLoop) GT 0>
                        <li>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                            <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,ListLoop) GT 0>
                                <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                            </cfif>
                            <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="reportSTATESGroupChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                            <label for="ReportSTATESGroup">#ListLoop#</label>
                        </li>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            </ul>

            <!--- For CALL RESULTS Group --->

            <ul class="list_permisstion">

                <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,Reporting_CallResults_Group_Title) GT 0>
                    <span class="label_permission"> 
                        <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                        <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,Reporting_CallResults_Group_Title) GT 0>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                        </cfif> 
                        <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_CallResults_Group_Title#" id="ReportSTATESGroup" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.reportCALLRESULTSGroupChilds','Reporting')" class="reportingCALLRESULTSChilds" value="#Reporting_CallResults_Group_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                        <label for="ReportCALLRESULTSGroup">#Reporting_CallResults_Group_Title#</label> 
                    </span>
                </cfif>

                <cfloop array="#Reporting_CallResultsGroup_List#" index="ListLoop" >

                    <cfif listfindNoCase(listAllPermission,ListLoop) GT 0>
                        <li>
                            <cfset Checked_checkbox = false>
                            <cfif listfindNoCase(checkedAllPermistion,ListLoop) GT 0>
                                <cfset Checked_checkbox = true>
                            </cfif>
                            <cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="reportCALLRESULTSGroupChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> 
                            <label for="ReportCALLRESULTSGroup">#ListLoop#</label>
                        </li>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            </ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: I tried just now but no change at all.

Comment: There are no checkboxes in your fiddle. If you're using a template, you need to copy the resulting HTML into the fiddle.

Comment: You need to give all the checkboxes a class for each of the nested groups they're in. So something under `Email Group` should have both `ReportingChild` and `EmailChild` classes.

Comment: @Barmar Could you please update my JSfiddle code for one group so that will help me in understanding it better. Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the classes of the sub-groups in your fiddle. I can't find the Email group.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the confusion, `Reporting_Group_Title` is used for 'Email Group'.You can use that for making changes. Similarly, 'Reporting Title' belongs to 'Reporting'. I am putting their values dynamically using pound sign in coldfusion. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What's the point of using jsfiddle if the code can't be executed? Post your code here in the question.

Comment: I don't know CF. I don't see where you're setting the classes of any of the checkboxes.

Comment: @user3239126 - You want to paste the *generated* HTML into the jsfiddle, not the raw CF code. So anyone can run the example in any browser. Right now it is not a "runnable" example because it contains server side code.

Comment: @Leigh How to paste generated HTML code? From Firebug? By the way since you know CF, are you able to understand my problem?

Comment: @Barmar Posted here: 

For example, considering 'Reporting_Title', I am using `onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.ReportingChilds', '')`

and class is defined in the <cfloop> tag in the following line:

`<cfinput type="checkbox" name="#ListLoop#" id="ListLoop" class="ReportingChilds" value="#ListLoop#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#"> `

ReportingChilds is the class name I have defined here.

Comment: @user3239126 - Yeah, you could paste it from Firebug or the old fashioned way: do a "view source" in the browser and copy+paste a small amount of the html. Just enough for a working fiddle example. (Edit) I do not have time to review the code right now, but if you paste the plain HTML I am sure these guys could assist you.

Comment: Okay, I did but it's not exactly generating the code as in the image. I hope it would help:Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4G3S/

Answer (score 0):

You have all the checkboxes in the block of `<ul class="list_permisstion">`. If I have you understood correctly you need to check all the checkboxes within that block. So basically you need to get all the checkboxes within that block. The jQuery find() function search through the descendants of the selected element which in your case will be the `<ul class="list_permisstion">`. Check http://api.jquery.com/find/.

The example function looks like that, where the childrenClass is a class name of the container of the checkboxes you need to check.

```
function parentCheckboxCheck(obj, childrenClass, parentId ){
        if($(obj).is(':checked')){
            $(childrenClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled',false);
            $(childrenClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',true);
        }
        else {
            $(childrenClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
            $(childrenClass).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled',true);
        }
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example for my one group ( say email group). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the fiddle I think you've got a couple of options.  One in your call to parentCheckboxCheck you can add each class that should be affected to the childrenClass parameters something like when the Reporting is checked the call would be parentCheckboxCheck(this, '.reportGroupChilds .reportSMSGroupChilds .reportSMSGroupChilds ect..") and just ignore the parentID.   The Other option would be to change the parentCheckboxcheck to traverse the DOM using JQuery to grab all elements after the that checkbox and check/disabled them there.

okay so code for the first option would be in your html

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_Title#" id="Reporting" onclick="parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.ReportingChilds, .reportGroupChilds, .reportSMSGro‌​upChilds, .reportSTATESGroupChilds, .reportCALLRESULTSGroupChilds', '')" value="#Reporting_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#">
```

for the second option I think something like this will work.

```
   function parentCheckboxCheck(obj, childrenClass, parentId ){
        var el = $(obj);
        el.closest('.list_permisstion')
            .find(':checkbox')
            .not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).prop('checked', el.is(':checked'));
            });
    };
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LYSRp/1/

I'm unclear on what you want disabled or enabled but I think this has the check functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I replaced `<cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_Title#" id="Reporting" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.ReportingChilds', '')" value="#Reporting_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#">` with `<cfinput type="checkbox" name="#Reporting_Title#" id="Reporting" onclick = "parentCheckboxCheck(this,'.ReportingChilds','.reportGroupChilds','.reportSMSGroupChilds','.reportSTATESGroupChilds','.reportCALLRESULTSGroupChilds')" value="#Reporting_Title#" checked="#Checked_checkbox#">` but it didn't work.

Comment: You should replace it with (this '.ReportingChilds, .reportGroupChilds, .reportSMSGro‌​upChilds, .reportSTATESGroupChilds, .reportCALLRESULTSGroupChilds') because they are all one selector.  before you were passing a bunch off different arguments.

Comment: Doing this is just selecting Email Group,SMS Group, State Group and Call Results group and not their childrens and that too for the very first time. When I click on Reporting checkbox again, nothign 
happens. Do you think there is a way to select the children elements too?

Comment: The second option is acting weird.

Comment: That's what I get for not testing.  edit should have the correct answer

Comment: your solution is making everything inactive after clicking first "Reporting" check box. What I am looking for is, even if after clicking first "Reporting", all checkboxes gets checked, if a user want to click, say for example, second Reporting, that should uncheck only it's childrens. I have modified the names of your solution in the new JSfiddle here. Also, please keep in mind that, "Reporting" is the main parent, then , EmailGroup , SMS Group are also children of Reporting and they have their own children.Please 
let me know if some thing is unclear.

Comment: Can you check my question?

Comment: @Leigh Can you check my question, if you have time now?